# Why are all HttpResponse's sent to dead letters (it worked fine so far)?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

This morning my code just stopped working. All the `HttpResponse`s are now sent *incorrectly* to `deadLetter`. What could be the issue?

```
class MyActor extends Actor {

  val mediator = DistributedPubSubExtension(context.system).mediator

  def receive = {
    case "tick" => {
      val pipeline = sendReceive ~> unmarshal[MyItems[Id]]
      val pipeline2: HttpRequest => Future[HttpResponse] = sendReceive

      val responseFuture: Future[MyItems[Id]] = pipeline(Get(path))
      responseFuture onComplete {
        case Success(json_items: MyItems[Id]) =>
          mediator.tell(DistributedPubSubMediator.Publish("I have response", ResponseTime(format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime())), self)  
        case Failure(t) => println("An error has occured: " + t.getMessage)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You need some more detail here. Add the specific deadLetter error message that you are receiving. Also, some of the "uninteresting" parts might aid comprehension here.

Comment: The dead letter is the HTTPResponse, the JSON that should come in the code (and it did before). No error from the REST server. Since I am new to Akka, tell me what else you need.

Comment: Probably I know where the problem is. I am using YOUTUBE API, that blocked me after probably a lot of requests, so the response was not parsable to MyItems and so the response was forwarded to DeadLetters. Does this make sense?

Comment: Could you eliminate calls to YouTube API and check something else you have control of? We'd spare few brain cycles then.

Comment: I added Thread.wait() between the calls and it works now. Looks like Youtube was sending incomplete results because of something (return code was 200, but it did not contain all the information)

Comment: You should consider posting your own answer and close the question then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that server was sending different messages and they were not parsable to MyItems object, so it caused error and the server response was forwarded to deadletters.